# Symfony - Doctrine Listener create url from name

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

can someone please explain, how to create listener to fill url field from name field without using existing slug libraries?

Example:

```
Name filed: this is an example #1
Url field: this-is-an-example-1
```

Now I have it in __constructor in entitiy... But I want to know how to use listeners... And I can't find example on google.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
/**
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class YourEntity
{
  /**
   * @ORM\PrePersist
   */
  public function slugify()
  {
    $name = $this->getName();
    $slug = functionToSlugify($name)
    $this->setUrl($slug);
  }
}
```

So you can create your own slugify function and before persisting your entity it will set your url for you.

That said, I highly recommend Doctrine Extension Bundle : 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/common_extensions.html

There's no point to reinvent the wheel ...

Comment: Thank you, that's it? I thought I have to create class in new folder like "listeners", then create service and then somehow call it in entity.

PS: I want it, not just for slug, but I'm trying to understand how it works, and how can it help me in future. Because as I said, I'm always using __constructor.

Comment: you can create a listener or a subscriber for that, but it's overkill for this case. Just use Doctrine native listener.